# Spark executor class create new serializer each time

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

I am using Spark 2.3.1 in local mode and I see all my threads are blocked on creating Kyro serializers.

When I look in the code I find this line:

```
(org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: 319)
val resultSer = env.serializer.newInstance()
```

Inside the method it using

```
val clazz = Utils.classForName(name)
```

on line 205, which is syncronized

[image: code screenshot]

Why not reuse the classes by utilizing `ThreadLocal` or other means?